# Qual a diferença de "esse", "este" e "aquele"?

Tags: adjectivos-demonstrativos

Qual é a forma correta de usar cada um deles? Quando empregar o "esse", "este" e "aquele"?

What's the difference between pronouns "esse", "este" e "aquele"? When to use each one?

Comment: Esta pergunta é como "isso", "isto" e "aquilo"?

Comment: @JorgeB. acho que sim. A não ser que haja alguma diferença quando usada nesta forma, o que eu acho que não.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Utilização dos pronomes demonstrativos `este`, `esse` e `aquele` para:

## Tempo

**Este**: tempo presente

> Este mês (atual) comprarei um carro.

**Esse**: tempo próximo, tanto para passado e futuro (dependerá do tempo verbal)

> Esse mês (passado) comprei um carro.
>
> Esse (próximo) mês comprarei um carro.

**Aquele**: tempo distante (novamente, depende do tempo verbal)

> 2000 foi inesquecível. Naquele ano ocorreu X, Y, Z, ...
>
> 2050 será inesquecível. Naquele ano ocorrerá X, Y, Z, ...

## Lugar

**Este**: utilizado quando o referencial (3ª pessoa) está próximo do emissor (1ª pessoa)

> Este brinco na minha orelha é meu.

**Esse**: utilizado quando o referencial (3ª pessoa) está próximo do destinatário (2ª pessoa)

> Quando comprou esse brinco que está na sua orelha?

**Aquele**: utilizado quando o referencial (3ª pessoa) está distante de ambos

> Vês aquele relatório sobre a mesa do Dr. Silva? É o documento a que me referi.

## Referindo-se a termos já citados

**Esse**: retoma um termo anterior (anáfora)

> João está doente, mas essa doença tem cura.

**Este**: precede um termo (catáfora)

> Nosso povo sofre com mutos problemas, dentre os quais estes: miséria, fome e ignorância.

**Retomando dois termos**: *aquele*, *este*

> As crianças da classe média têm um futuro mais promissor do que os filhos de pais das classes menos favorecidas, porque àquelas (crianças) se dão oportunidades que se negam a estes (pais).

**Retomando três termos**: *aquele*, *esse*, *este*

> O velho, o índio e o negro são discriminados por motivos diversos: aquele (velho), por ser improdutivo para a sociedade de consumo; esse (índio), por ser considerado atrasado e preguiçoso; este (negro), por não se ter libertado, ainda, do estigma da escravidão.

Link útil: http://hmg.pucrs.br/manualred/pronomes.php

Comment: Em português europeu (pt-PT), não se usa "esse" relativo a tempo (excepto em anáfora). Fora isso, a resposta é perfeita para pt-PT também.

Answer (score 8):

## Esse/Essa

O elemento a que se refere já foi citado no contexto, e queremos nos referir a ele novamente.

> Estamos falando de uma pergunta. Essa pergunta já foi respondida.

## Este/Esta

O elemento ao qual queremos nos referir ainda não foi citado no contexto.

> Esta pergunta já foi respondida e ainda não tinha sido citada.

## Aquele/Aquela

O elemento ao qual queremos nos referir não está próximo, sob algum ponto de vista.

> Aquela outra pergunta ainda não tinha sido respondida.

---

**In English**

## Esse/Essa

The referred element was already mentioned in the context, and we want to refer to it again.

> Estamos falando de uma pergunta. Essa pergunta já foi respondida.

## Este/Esta

The element to which we refer has not been mentioned in the context.

> Esta pergunta já foi respondida e ainda não tinha sido citada.

## Aquele/Aquela

The element to which we refer is not close, under any point of view.

> Aquela outra pergunta ainda não tinha sido respondida.

Comment: Além do que consta na resposta, existem as variantes de **tempo** e **lugar**.

Comment: Sim, a outra resposta é melhor, portanto.

Comment: Ahhh. Eu não tinha visto a outra resposta, @Cigano.