# Como se devem empregar "isto", "este" e relacionados no português do Brasil?

Tags: pronomes, diferenças-transatlânticas, determinantes, adjectivos-demonstrativos

Sei muito bem do português de Portugal que os determinantes/pronomes demonstrativos *isto*, *este*, e possíveis variações e contrações (*estes*, *deste*, *nisto*, ...) são usados para apontar a alguma coisa relativamente próxima à pessoa que fala, dentro do contexto envolvido.

> Estes vasos foram envernizados.
>
> O José já me deve 70 euros! Isto não fica por aqui!

Contudo, tenho observado várias situações de português do Brasil, tanto escrito como falado, em que optam por usar os determinantes *isso*, *esse* e respetivas variações, **perante as mesmas circunstâncias**, que normalmente referem a alguma coisa próxima de um recetor. Um exemplo correto em Portugal seria:

> Esse computador à tua frente está avariado, Edgar.

A definição de [*isto*](http://www.dicio.com.br/isto/) parece ser a mesma, mas pela leitura de alguns textos (como [este](http://unesp.br/aci_ses/conteudo.php?conteudo=1364)), algo me diz que existem diferenças cruciais e que mais frequentemente recorrem ao segundo grupo de determinantes/pronomes.

No Brasil, quais são os critérios de escolha entre a "isto" e "isso", e entre palavras do mesmo género? Que terá levado à existência destas diferenças?

Comment: Excelente pergunta +1

Comment: Relacionada ou possível duplicata (não fala de *isto*): http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-esse-este-e-aquele

Comment: Essa pergunta e respetivas respostas não apresentam a diferença entre as duas variantes da língua.

Comment: Foi assim que aprendi no colégio, vou ver se consigo formular uma resposta -> http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/colunas/noutraspalavras/ult2675u20.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No português coloquial brasileiro, "isso" e "isto" são usados como sinônimos, sem que se faça diferença entre eles, mas com grande preferência por "isso". A situação é análoga para essa/esta ou este/esse.

No padrão culto, o uso é o mesmo do português europeu, isto é (resumidamente),

> isto/esta/este - próximo à primeira pessoa, acontecimento presente ou
>   futuro, aquilo que o texto passará a expor, o primeiro de uma série de
>   três.
>
> isso/essa/esse - próximo à segunda pessoa, acontecimento passado,
>   aquilo que o texto acaba de referir, o segundo de uma série de três.
>
> aquilo/aquela/aquele - distante da primeira e da segunda pessoas,
>   acontecimento passado e relativamente remoto, o terceiro de uma série
>   de três.

Portanto,

> *isto aqui*, *isso aí*, *aquilo lá*;
>
> *isto vai ser bom*, *isso foi ótimo*, *aquilo tinha sido complicado*;
>
> *isto é claro: a proposta é inconstitucional*,
>
> *a proposta é inconstitucional, isso é claro*;
>
> *este propõe a reforma do sistema penitenciário, esse quer penas mais duras, aquele prefere a lei de Talião*.

Como sói acontecer, o uso coloquial vai aos poucos invadindo o padrão, e o sistema ternário isto/isso/aquilo acabará eventualmente substituído por um binário isso/aquilo:

> *isso/isto aqui*, *isso/isto aí*, *aquilo lá*;
>
> *isso/isto que vou dizer agora*;
>
> *isso/isto que acabo de dizer*,
>
> *esse/este propõe a reforma do sistema penitenciário, aquele quer penas mais duras, aquele outro prefere a lei de Talião*.

Comment: Curiosamente, passei ontem pelo [Manual de redação da Folha de São Paulo](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/circulo/manual_texto_e.htm), e reparei na recomendação do uso culto de *este/esse*, o que indica que só por si indica usos divergentes.

Comment: Acho importante mencionar o uso dêitico desses pronomes: https://www.estudopratico.com.br/deixis-referencia-deitica-o-que-e-e-para-que-serve/

Answer (score 3):

Nota: Deixo esta resposta como resultado da minha investigação pessoal, mas que no final não me ajudou a esclarecer a questão fulcral. Já encontrei demasiadas ocorrências de "isso"/"esse" no português do Brasil que não encaixaria nesta definição (e que em português de Portugal não seria normal). Vou manter o que tenho escrito, mas deve haver uma resposta melhor para justificar esta confusão.

---

Uma investigação sobre o tópico leva-me a crer que há realmente uma pequena diferença na forma como são empregues estes pronomes (irei focar-me nas palavras *isso* e *isto*).

O dicionário online de portuguẽs (BR) inclui uma definição de [isso](http://www.dicio.com.br/isso/) peculiar, mencionada até numa [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/11/84) a outra pergunta:

> Tem relação com o que acabou de ser dito: «ela não foi ao trabalho e *isso* é grave»

Contrastando, a mesma definição no português de Portugal pode aplicar-se a **isto** ([referência](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/isso--esse--isto--este/9168)): para além de ser empregue quando este pronome se refere a um ser que se encontra perto de quem fala, há também que:

> Designa qualquer coisa a que já nos referimos ou que seguidamente se vai explicar: «Ele disse isto, sem saber o que dizia. *Isto* de aturar uma pessoa assim é coisa muito difícil.»

Em suma, as duas variantes do português adotam pronomes demonstrativos diferentes face à situação em que pretendemos referir alguma coisa já mencionada (**isto** no PT-EU e **isso** no PT-BR).

Comment: "ela não foi ao trabalho e isso é grave" 'Isso' para algo que aconteceu anteriormente, e está sendo mencionado agora. "Isto de aturar uma pessoa assim é coisa muito difícil" 'Isto' para algo que acaba de ser mencionado, ou acaba de acontecer no tempo do texto, algo presente.

Comment: https://www.estudopratico.com.br/deixis-referencia-deitica-o-que-e-e-para-que-serve/

Comment: @Lambie [*Muito* relacionado](https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/8/8142/tde-08122005-210454/publico/disserta.pdf) — e também relevante para algumas outras discussões sobre a dêixis em outros sites de Stack Exchange.