# Deste vs. Desse vs. Daquele

Tags: pronomes, preposições

According to [Sonia-Portuguese.com, section 11](http://www.sonia-portuguese.com/language/grammar/pronouns/#Demonstrative%20Pronouns%20and%20Preposition%20de) (Question Words), *deste, desse, daquele* all mean "this". What is the difference between these?!?

> Você gosta **desta** blusa? = Do you like **this** blouse?
>
> Eu gosto **desse** café. = I like **this** coffee.
>
> Eu gosto **daqueles** sapatos. = I like **those** shoes.

I don't understand how to distinguish between these because the words seem interchangeable. Extremely confused right now. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related: [Qual a diferença de “esse”, “este” e “aquele”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-esse-este-e-aquele)

Comment: The "Remarks" in Section 9 on that same page appears to explain everything in your question. Could you [edit] your question to explain what is really confusing you, in light of that explanation? Otherwise you're asking for answers that say the same thing, and thus probably wouldn't address your real confusion?

Comment: Whoops, I see now, that table in section 11 looks like one big typo. I see how that could be confusing.

Comment: This also super confusing on Duolingo how do you differentiate in written language that the object is far from both the first and second persons.

Comment: You should open a question, we'll be glad to clarify and explain any doubts you have. The other question linked by Jacinto explains perfectly the "farness" of the objects related to este/esse/aquele: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-esse-este-e-aquele

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [table and first example in section 11](http://www.sonia-portuguese.com/language/grammar/pronouns/#Demonstrative%20Pronouns%20and%20Preposition%20de) are misleading, but the remarks in [section 9](http://www.sonia-portuguese.com/language/grammar/pronouns/#Demonstrative%20Pronouns) are correct and address your question: roughly speaking, *deste* means *of this*, not just *this*; and *desse* and *daquele* mean *of that*. The first thing to know is these words are contractions of the preposition *de* with a pronoun:

> deste = de + este [of this (near the speaker)]
>
> desse = de + esse [of that (near the person you’re speaking to)]
>
> daquele = de + aquele [of that (over there)]

The differences among [*este, esse*, and *aquele* are addressed at length in this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-esse-este-e-aquele). I'll focus on the role of the preposition *de*. The reason it looks as though *deste* means *this* in some sentences is that some Portuguese verbs need the preposition *de* whereas the English equivalents do not need any preposition. For instance *gostar de (something)* is equivalent to *like (something)*:

> Eu gosto ***de*** vinho = I like wine
>
> ***Este*** vinho é bom = ***this*** wine is good
>
> Eu gosto ***deste*** vinho = I like this wine

In the last example it looks as though *deste* means *this*, but it does not: it means *of this*, except the verb *like* does not take any preposition, whereas *gostar* takes *de*. The site’s second example is correct: to ask for someone’s opinion on something you can use *think of (something)* and *achar de (something)*:

> O que voçê acha ***deste*** vinho? = what do you think ***of this*** wine?
>
> Acho que ***este*** vinho é muito bom = I think ***this*** wine is very good

Comment: To be fair, the site *does* say that it is a contraction meaning "of this".

Comment: @DanGetz True, but the table in section 11 show *deste, desse, daquele* = *this*, and that's wrong.

Comment: @DanGetz Ok, I think I'm doing justice to the site now.

Comment: @Jacinto does it again! Thank you everyone for pointing out that section 11 in the link is incorrect. Beginners can't tell the difference ;) Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

That is a mistranslation. *Gosto desse café* should have been translated to *I like that coffee*.

Of course, now you have *esse* and *aquele* both mapping to *that*. The difference is that *esse* refers something close to the person you're talking to, while *aquele* refers to something distant from both participants. If the use is not related to location and is instead anaphoric, you would generally  use *esse*, tough there are many nuances there.