# Qual pronome utilizar para retomar o termo anterior: "este" ou "esse"

Tags: pronomes

Recentemente estava lendo um livro de Direito Administrativo e eis que me deparo com o seguinte trecho (grifo meu):

> O Direito é historicamente divido em dois grandes ramos: Direito Público e o Direito Privado. **Nesse**, vale o princípio da isonomia entre as partes.

Eu sei que o trecho refere-se ao ramo do Direito Privado, porém o correto não seria utilizar ***neste*** devido a o termo *Direito Privado* estr mais próximo? E se quiséssemos retomar o termo *Direito Público*, qual pronome utilizaríamos?

A frase abaixo está correta até onde sei. O pronome ***esse*** retoma o segundo elemento mais distante, diferente do trecho acima.

> *Aline*, *Bianka* e *Naiane* foram à festa, pois **esta** (*Naiane*) casou, **aquela** (*Aline*) noivou e **essa** (*Bianka*) passou no vestibular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qual a diferença de "esse", "este" e "aquele"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-de-esse-este-e-aquele)

Comment: @Peixoto eu deixaria ficar a pergunta aberta, pela sua especificidade, tenho sempre dúvidas também.

Comment: @Peixoto Eu já havia lido essa pergunta antes de postar a minha. Achei ela bastante ampla. Sei sobre os termos anafóricos e catafóricos, por isso "estranhei" o "nesse". Na pergunta "linkada" há apenas exemplos amplos com "aquele, este" e "aquele, esse, este".

Comment: Na pergunta linkada pelo Peixoto, o último ponto da resposta mais votada parece-me de facto responder à segunda metade desta pergunta. Será que devíamos editar a pergunta para salientar melhor a dúvida e a diferença dela para a tal pergunta, Valdeir?

Comment: @ANeves Discordo. Na minha última frase, eu afirmo que — até onde eu sei — a frase está correta e que ela é diferente do trecho encontrado no livro. A dúvida é *somente* com a primeira frase. Na frase *linkada* há um exemplo com dois termos, porém o exemplo fica "preso" somente com o *aquele* e *este*. Minha dúvida é entre *esse" e *este* quando há dois termos (obviamente, no contexto apresentado na pergunta).

Comment: Também acho que a dúvida nesta pergunta (uso isolado de "esse" para referir o mais distante de dois termos anteriores) não é coberto na resposta à outra pergunta (que menciona apenas o uso de "esse" em conjunto com "este" e "aquele", e o uso conjunto de "este" e "aquele"). Nem seria de esperar que uma pergunta tão genérica cobrisse todas as dúvidas possíveis. Mas é boa prática referenciar perguntas e respostas relacionadas, e salientar a diferença (por que é que a outra resposta não responde a este caso). Creio que passava por aí a ideia do @ANeves.

Comment: Sim, era isso. A outra pergunta não cobrindo esta, era bom explicitar a diferença; ficava uma pergunta mais forte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse uso de *esse* não está de acordo com os dicionários. Deveria ser *este*, como sugeriste, para a última entidade e *aquele* (ou *esse*) para a primeira. Vejamos o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002; desenvolvi algumas abreviações):

> **este** /ê/ *pron.dem.* […] **3** combinado com *aquele* ou *esse*, serve para fazer referência a duas pessoas ou coisas já mencionadas, indicando a última, ao passo que, *aquele* ou *esse* representa a primeira <*o Pedro e o Paulo foram despedidos: este por incompetência, aquele porque faltava muito ao trabalho*>

Encontramos a mesma coisa no [Aulete (7)](http://www.aulete.com.br/aquele), [Michaelis (4)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/aquele/), dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001), e *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 420; podes [aqui uma edição anterior](http://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap09-05-pronomes_demonstrativos)) . Mesma coisa, com uma exceção: todas estas obras referem apenas *este* para a última entidade e *aquele*, mas não *esse*, para a primeira. Também não encontrei nenhum exemplo com *esse*.

Nota também que o uso mais usual é usar-se *este* juntamente com *aquele*, e não um deles isoladamente. Repara que o Houaiss diz que se usa *este* combinado com *aquele*. As outras obras sugerem a mesma coisa, ainda que com linguagem menos categórica. Portanto, de acordo com o uso mais usual, poderia ser:

> O Direito é historicamente divido em dois grandes ramos: Direito Público e o Direito Privado. Neste [Direito Privado], vale o princípio da isonomia entre as partes; **daquele** [Direito Público], falaremos mais adiante.

Dos vários exemplos que vi, encontrei apenas um com o pronome sozinho; mas ainda assim o outro pronome estava implícito (… esta era muito mais bonita [que aquela]):

> Hoje saí para ver umas bolsas. Gostei de uma preta e de uma azul, mas sem dúvida ESTA era muito mais bonita.
> [(Maria H. Moura Neves, *Gramática de usos do português*, 2000, citado em Talita de Cássia Marine, *O uso anafórico dos pronomes demonstrativos…*, 2014, p. 20](http://books.scielo.org/id/z7jnq/pdf/costa-9788568334416-03.pdf)

Poderás também querer ver [este artigo sobre o assunto](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/cotidian/ff2410200204.htm) do professor de português Pasquale Cipro Neto na Folha de São Paulo (2002) e este [*É com “t” ou com “s”?*](http://www.revisereveja.com.br/2011/02/e-com-t-ou-com-s.html) de Hugo Maciel de Carvalho.

Não encontrei o uso conjunto de *este, esse* e *aquele* do teu último exemplo em nenhuma das obras que consultei. Deve portanto ser pouco comum.

### Um uso anafórico diferente de *esse*

Vem nos dicionários um uso anafórico de *esse* (ainda pronome substantivo), mas é diferente. Trata-se de um uso especial para referir uma única coisa, sem a distinguir de outra. Citando o Houaiss:

> **esse** /ê/ *pron.dem.* [...] **7** emprega-se anaforicamente para representar enfaticamente um termo da frase que está na ordem inversa (topicalizado) <*o ardor da juventude, esse, ele perdeu*>

Comment: Jacinto, então, quando não é necessário comparar usamos sempre "esse"? Exemplo, "Os utilizadores deviam adicionar uma resposta. Essa(Esta?) resposta deve ser bem concisa."

Comment: Outro exemplo, referindo-se à tua resposta aqui: "Esta(Essa?) resposta não está correta".

Comment: @Jacinto, A fonte da outra pergunta é http://hmg.pucrs.br/manualred/pronomes.php. Além dela, frases com os três pronomes (**este**, **esta** e **aquela**) podem ser encontradas em https://blog.enem.com.br/pronome-demonstrativo-este-ou-esse/ e numa aula do professor e escritor *Adriano Paciello* ( https://postimg.cc/QVMkC1tv ). Porém, no livro *A Gramática para Concursos* (*Fernando Pestana*), ele afirma que, por falta de respaldo, não está adequada a estrutura com os três pronomes na mesma frase. *Buguei Oo*

Comment: @JorgeB. De acordo com *Evanildo Bechara*, em *Moderna Gramática Portuguesa*: “no discurso, quando o falante deseja fazer menção ao que ele acabou de narrar (anáfora) ou ao que vai narrar (catáfora), emprega este (e flexões)”. Fonte: http://books.scielo.org/id/z7jnq/pdf/costa-9788568334416-03.pdf (pág.: 5).

Comment: @Valdeir, eu imaginei que a construção com esse/este/aquele tivesse sido usada,  mas que deve ser rara, visto não aparecer nos dicionários que consultei. Não me preocupei muito com ela, visto a tua pergunta ser sobre o primeiro exemplo.

Comment: @Jorge, os *este/esse* dos teu exemplos são determinantes ("esta/essa resposta") em vez de pronomes substantivos (*este* ou *esse* sem mais nada) que é o que temos **nesta** pergunta. Aí, eu digo **esta** resposta (e está correta, claro :)), porque estou a escrever um comentário debaixo dela; mas "é preciso outra resposta; **essa** resposta deve ser...", para distinguir **desta**, que é a minha. A escolha entre *este X* e *esse X* depende do contexto, e nalguns casos não faz diferença.>>

Comment: @JorgeB., >> Mas "devemos investir a educação porque esta é fundamental para o futuro"; neste caso (*este* sem mais nada, pronome substantivo) é sempre *este*, como disse o Valdeir acima. O exemplo final com *esse* que lá estava é um uso especial, tal como o que lá está agora (tinha-me enganado).

Comment: @Jacinto quem precisa de umas aulas de português sou eu :D

Comment: @Jorge, eu parece-me que isto pode ser complicado só de explicar, porque uma pessoa ao falar, se seguir a intuição safa-se bem. Tu se não tivesse focado conscientemente no *este* versus *esse*, ter-te-ias referido à minha resposta por "esta resposta", porque ela está aqui.

Comment: @Jacinto o problema é que eu estou em constante contacto com o pt-BR e vejo muitas vezes "essa resposta". E daí a minha confusão.

Comment: @Jorge, no Brasil é comum usar *esse* no lugar de *este* e vice versa [(Aulete 2,5)](http://www.aulete.com.br/esse). Mas pode ser *essa* (mesmo em Portugal) quando tu mencionas uma resposta (que não está "aqui") e eu respondo "também vi essa resposta (que tu acabaste de mencionar)"; aqui não tem nada que ver com lugar; *essa* refere-se simplesmente ao que tu (ou quem estiver a falar comigo) mencionaste.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade *nesse* (*em* + *esse*) refere-se ao direito público, enquanto *neste* (*em* + *este*) pode-se referir ao direito privado.