# Em ligações (links HTTP), deve-se usar o pronome "neste" ou "nesse"?

Tags: pronomes

A realização de ligações entre um documento a outro recurso é muito comum nos dias de hoje, principalmente na internet. Nesse sentido, ao utilizar um link, é correto usar `neste` ou `nesse`?

Por exemplo:

- Confira [**nesse** documento](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6564/ao-usarmos-liga%c3%a7%c3%b5es-links-devemos-usar-neste-ou-nesse) algumas informações adicionais.
- Confira [**neste** documento](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6564/ao-usarmos-liga%c3%a7%c3%b5es-links-devemos-usar-neste-ou-nesse) algumas informações adicionais.

Qual dos dois está gramaticalmente correto, e por quê?

Comment: O correto é *neste*. O pronome *este* é catafórico, ou seja, ele faz referência a um termo posterior (documento).

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, não queres escrever isso numa resposta? Responder em comentários não é nada kosher...

Comment: @ANeves, às vezes estou no celular e isso dificulta escrever uma resposta "completa" com fontes, exemplos etc. Pelo fato de ter que buscar informações na internet. Neste caso, prefiro deixar uma informação que possa servir para dar um "norte" ao autor da pergunta ou outro usuário que possa elaborar uma resposta melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a gramática mais tradicional, e especialmente no português europeu, como o Valdeir Psr indicou em comentário (e como respondido na [segunda pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/2/2764) deste site (!)), o correto é **este**, por fazer referência a um termo que ainda está por vir no texto. Veja, e.g., essa [questão](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/esteesseissoisto/3677) no Ciberdúvidas e esta [página](https://www.bbc.com/portuguese/brasil-39646836).

Já no português brasileiro, a preferência é pelo **esse**, que nos parece mais natural - como colocado nessa outra [questão](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-dos-demonstrativos-esse-e-este-outra-vez/21282) do Ciberdúvidas:

> Quando o pronome ocorre isolado, o mais frequente, e o aconselhado em Portugal, é recorrer a este. Acontece que no Brasil parece haver uma clara preferência pelo pronome esse em detrimento de este, no mesmo contexto.

e nesta [dissertação](https://teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/8/8142/tde-08122005-210454/publico/disserta.pdf) (Hélcius Batista Pereira, USP 2005):

> os  brasileiros  só  fazem  uso  significativo  de  "este"  nos  gêneros   marcados   por   uma   maior   pressão   da   norma   gramatical   dos   manuais.   Os   portugueses,  no  entanto,  mantêm  o  sistema  ternário,  ainda  ancorado  na  questão  espacial  /  no campo de interlocução,  tanto na fala como na escrita.
>
> Nos  tipos  de  textos  em  que  a  norma  dos  manuais  se  impõe,
> os  dois  sistemas  encontram  espaço  para  optar  livremente  cada
> qual  por  uma  forma:  o  português  opta  por  "este", enquanto o
> brasileiro, por "esse".
>
> A  presente  pesquisa  contestou  a  interpretação  de  Marine  (2004)
> que  via  na  oralidade  brasileira  um  caso  de  especialização  de
> formas  em  função  do  tipo  de  referência.  Os nossos dados
> mostraram que na fala do brasileiro a forma "este" é apenas residual e
> está em vias de substituição por "esse".

Comment: A própria resposta é um exemplo de inconsistência no uso de esse/este: "Veja, e.g., **essa** questão no Ciberdúvidas e **esta** página."; "como colocado **nessa** outra questão do Ciberdúvidas e **nesta** dissertação". Garanto que não foi proposital. :-)